# Table reference not working properly when using \setcounter{table}{0} in appendix in latex

Tags: latex

I am trying to fix an issue with my latex document, and need help.

I am using `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` environment in Latex. The issue is the following:

I have added an appendix using

```
\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix_a}
```

and used

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
```

to generate table names as Table A1 and so on.

However, when I use `\setcounter` to restart the table numbering, my labels stop working. But if I remove the `\setcounter` command, my labels work perfectly, but then the table number continue from where I left before appendix, that is Table A6 and not Table A1.

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,apacite,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}


\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

Table \ref{tab_main} is the first table.

\begin{table}
\centering
 \input{Main_Table}
\caption{Main Table}
\label{tab_main}
\end{table}

See table \ref{tab_appendix} in the appendix.

\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix_a}

%\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\begin{table}
    \input{Appendix_Table}
    \caption{Appendix Table}
\label{tab_appendix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And here are tables that I have used:
Main_Table.tex

```
\begin{centre}
\begin{table}[H]
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\small
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Koo} & A & B & C \\
\tiny
\end{tabularx}
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\smallskip
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize{\emph{Notes}: Main}}}
\end{table}
\end{centre}
```

Appendix_Table.tex

```
\begin{centre}
\begin{table}[H]
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\small
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Foo} & A & B & C \\
\tiny
\end{tabularx}
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\smallskip
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize{\emph{Notes}: Appendix}}}
\end{table}
\end{centre}
```

Any help on this front would be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,apacite,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

Table \ref{tab_main} is the first table.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
main table
\caption{Main Table}
\label{tab_main}
\end{table}

See table \ref{tab_appendix} in the appendix.

\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix_a}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\theHtable}{\thetable}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
appendix table
\caption{Appendix Table}
\label{tab_appendix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You So Much!:)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while having a similar issue. And the answer does solve the issue completely. But I had another use case where I have several Appendix Section (Appendix A, B and so on). In this case the table was not numbering proprely (using the provided solution by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ) Therefore I modified the code by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz a little bit to have proper table numbers corresponding to the each appendix.

Maybe someone will also have the same use case as mine. I am just a beginner in latex but I hope it helps someone in the future like it helped me this time.

I have changed this `\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}` to `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}`

Minimum working example below:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable, adjustbox,apacite,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

Table \ref{tab_main} is the first table.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
main table
\caption{Main Table}
\label{tab_main}
\end{table}

See table \ref{tab_appendix} in the appendix.

See table \ref{tab_appendix_B} in appendix B
\clearpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix_a}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\theHtable}{\thetable}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
appendix table
\caption{Appendix Table}
\label{tab_appendix}
\end{table}

\section{Appendix B}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
appendix table 
\caption{Appendix Table}
\label{tab_appendix_B}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you :)